# what should be the order of the code .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

the url is returning to login path on any process, i think the code order is wrong in `ConfigureServices`  how can i fix it?

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDI();//custom Startup Collection
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
            {

                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            }).AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityValidator.CustomIdentityValidator>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));//
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
   
            
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
            services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);//appsettingstekileri değiştirecek
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("global", cors =>
                {
                    cors.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {

                options.Cookie.Name = "test";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20);
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/SignIn";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
            });
        }
```

Configure:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager, IWebSiteBussRepository webSiteBussRepository)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }


            IdentityInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).Wait();
            IdentityInitializer.StaticPage(webSiteBussRepository).Wait();

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/StatusCode", "?code={0}"); //en üstte olmalı 404 page 'i için yazdım
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            //app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("global");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "areas",
                     pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                     );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                   );
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have logged-in and put some well-fit authorize on the endpoint ? If so... might we see your `Configure` method (`ConfigureServices` registering things, `Configure` use them to build a pipeline)

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. i posted `Configure` below.

Comment: You can check the [Asp.net Core Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order), the `UseCors`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must appear in the order shown: the call to `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru0A9.png). Try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet... I might found your problem here...

Notice that behind the scene, `app.UseIdentityServer();` make use of `IdentityServerMiddleware` (which is a specific middleware for Identity Server), and make use of `app.UseIdentityServer();` above it, the code can be found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L44), and this is what [that line execute](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions.cs).

In short, Identity server leave the authenticating process for `AuthenticationMiddleware`, which got register by `app.UseAuthentication();`, and they will process additional logic later.

So, the pipeline order should be

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCors("global");

// or just this to be compact:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("global");
```